# websocket, http or both?

Tags: sockets, http, web

Writing a one page web application, and knowing that some of the screens would need real-time updates, I am faced to one big general question, whatever API and frontend framework and language I am going to use:

**I'll implement data transfer over websocket, should I keep `http` for any data transfer which would not need real-time updates, or should I just use websocket?**

Knowing that websockets are not handled on ALL browsers but most if not all recent ones support it, would it be better for the servers to handle both websocket and http, or should I just use websockets for ALL data transfer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably end up using both WebSockets and HTTP requests at the end.

WebSockets, because it sounds like you need them (because of the real-time updates) and can afford to require browser support for them (otherwise, you'd be forced to use the older Ajax/Comet based approaches).

HTTP for two possible reasons:

- You will sooner or later need a blocking request-response behavior. For example, authenticating a user may need to block for the result before further processing happens, so you need to send a request for authentication and block until you get the result. This can be a bit annoying to handle over WebSockets.
- You may need to load heavy data without interrupting the ongoing real-time updates. If you were to load such data over WebSockets (as a single big chunk), it will be queued together with the real-time updates and may delay them.

Both of these issues can be handled over WebSockets, but they are simply easier to solve with simple HTTP Ajax requests.

Comment: thank, while @ManoNamo and @Apero comments on previous answer are adding value to the Q/A, that was the kind of answer I was looking for! One thing tho, the first point about locking the user, I think in a one page application (done right) you should be able to lock the user with or without anything running in the backend, so I wouldn't take this as a blocker for my choice, but yeah, **I'll use both websockets and http, and take care to do the `findAll` or slow API calls over HTTP instead**.

Answer (score 0):

Use websockets for the following needs,

1. Server data changes frequently
2. Multi-user communication
3. Live feeds etc.,

Refer [this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071232/java-app-dev/9-killer-uses-for-websockets.html) for better understanding on websocket usage.

Comment: Yes I know about websocket, but my question is `should I use ONLY websocket since I'll need it anyway, or should I use a mix of websocket and http in the same application?`

Comment: My suggestion would be use a mix of websockets & http. If your application is in need request-response model, streaming etc., then http would be the savior. Apologies for the answer provided above.

Comment: No worries! And thank you.  Can you explain or send a link that explain why using a mix would be better than just using websockets?

Comment: Refer - Section: Does WebSocket Replace HTTP? in http://www.unionplatform.com/?page_id=2954
I will post further analysis later ...

Comment: I use websockets for low payload transfer more like rpc type APIs, events, and I use http for big payloads. However, make sure that you implement a fallback to http when the browser does not support websockets.