# Websocket client messaging, vs HTTP requests

Tags: http, websocket

I have started to develop a Rails application, and decided to use websockets as a way to push notifications to the client - and am using basic HTTP requests to get and manipulate data on the server.
Now, websockets allows you to send messages from the client to the server, a feature I currently am not sure when to use - I mean I can always do post requests.

This feels somewhat odd to me - so I guess I am doing something wrong - why should I send HTTP requests when there is already a connection between the client and the server? it could just send a message through the websocket, and request the data to be pushed back to it.

I guess the websocket protocol isn't meant to fully replace http - and servers should support both - so I am wondering, what was the intended usage? - when should I send messages from the client through the websocket and when should I use POST for example?

Comment: I wrote an answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26374699/websocket-http-or-both/26377429#26377429 :)

Comment: If I know all my clients support websockets - should I still support HTTP?

Comment: You will probably still need Ajax requests when you want to load something in parallel to the traffic flow over the websocket connection (say you are refreshing a big chunk of data), or when you need to blocking call.